# Xamarin.Forms: Page with CSS transformations and JS swiping doesn't work in Android WebView custom renderer, when it does in Chrome

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-webview, custom-renderer

What could be the cause of a HTML page loaded over HTTPS with CSS transformations and JavaScript that uses “swiping” to not work in a Xamarin.Forms Android WebView custom renderer?

The page works fine in: Chrome on Android, Xamarin.Android WebView, Xamarin.Forms WebView.

Only when using a WebView custom renderer on Android [according to the official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) does the page stop working.

Specifically, it's pages like these that fail to work for some reason: https://www.irozhlas.cz/fotogalerie/7693434?fid=8301190

Found another type of pages that doesn't display correctly in an Android WebView custom renderer: https://www.irozhlas.cz/ekonomika/kalkulacka-socialni-davky-exekuce_1811280900_jab – this leads me to believe it's a CSS issue, not a JS one.

I understand this is quite a narrow scope, but I'm sure others must have run into similar problems.

**I have tried:**

- No relevant errors or warnings seem to appear in the log.
- Remote debugging on Chrome: there are no warnings or signs of why it wouldn't work. I wasn't able to find the cause in the page's JS or CSS.
- Updating the Xamarin.Forms package.
- Setting HttpClient implementation to Android (AndroidClientHandler).
- The following, gathered from other Stack Overflow answers and other places, but it doesn't make a difference:

  ```
  webView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
  webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
  webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
  webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
  webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
  webView.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;

  webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
  webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
  webView.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;
  webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
  webView.Settings.DefaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8";

  webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  ```

Using Xamarin.Forms with a custom renderer for the WebView should have been the equivalent of using Xamarin.Android, but upon further investigation, a Xamarin.Android project with a WebView works fine with the page, and so does the default Xamarin.Forms WebView, thus this seems to be a Xamarin.Forms WebView custom renderer specific problem.

Comment: Could you share your custom renderer?

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/FasjQmcB 
It should be 1:1 to the aforementioned tutorial – https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Comment: @BillyLiu-MSFT I've managed to find a solution to the problem: creating the WebView in a custom page renderer (see the answer). It looks like the cause is missing webView.LayoutParameters. Could this be the case for Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've found is to create the Android WebView inside a custom page renderer for Android. In this example, the page with the WebView is called `MyPage`.

On other platforms, you can use the regular `MyPage` Xamarin.Forms.Page with Xamarin.Forms.WebView, or WebView custom renderers. As mentioned in the question, on Android, the custom renderer for the WebView has problems with certain kinds of pages.

```
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace MyXamarinApp.Droid
{
    public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        WebView webView;

        public MyPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            webView = new WebView(this.Context);

            // If you're using AXML to “inflate” the layout, you would use something like this instead:
            //webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);

            // Important: LayoutParameters don't do anything for the layout (because the parent Xamarin.Forms page is a FrameLayout and doesn't do any automatic layout), but leaving this out is what causes the problems
            webView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FillParent, LayoutParams.FillParent);

            // Here you can set the WebView settings, WebViewClient, CookieManager, AddJavascriptInterface etc.
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            webView.LoadUrl("https://www.example.com/");

            this.AddView(webView);

            /*// The following works but breaks Xamarin.Forms:
            Activity activity = this.Context as Activity;
            activity.SetContentView(webView);*/
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

            webView.Layout(left, top, right, bottom); // Important because LayoutParameters doesn't have an effect
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like leaving out the line `webView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FillParent, LayoutParams.FillParent);` is what causes the WebView problems. Perhaps this is what's missing in the Xamarin.Forms custom renderer?