# Web page height correctly rendered with WebViewRenderer, but not with ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview, custom-renderer

There is something different between the default `WebViewRenderer` and my custom `ViewRenderer` and I have to find out why. Basically, the web page isn't displayed if I use my custom `ViewRenderer`.

The `ViewRenderer` has some issues with `height: 100%;` and interprets this CSS wrong. As result the height is 0px, despite it should use the full height. On the other side it works with exact sizes (e.g. 400px).

Code for `WebViewRenderer`:

```xml
<local:CustomWebView x:Name="webView"
     Source="http://somesite"
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     HeightRequest="1000"
     WidthRequest="1000"/>
```

```cs
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
}

public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

Code for `ViewRenderer`:

```xml
<local:HybridWebView x:Name="webView"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HeightRequest="1000"
                     WidthRequest="1000"/>
```

```cs
public class HybridWebView : View
{
}

public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
{
    private Context context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(this.context);
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.LoadUrl("http://somesite");
        }
    }
}

public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{

}
```

One assumption is that the responsive website adapts to its `WebView` size, and since the rendering process takes place in background it somehow has a height of zero at this time.

Comment: can you check if same url works with http instead of https

Comment: @Gautam: To open the URL I make some web requests to get the correct login tokens (OAuth). Once I have my URL I show it in the `WebView`. Here it makes no difference if I use `http` or `https`. Tested on both - the device and emulator.

Comment: You can create a  class inherit WebChromeClient, then replace of ` var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(this.context);`

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT: I already tried to use `webView.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this.context));`, but nothing changes. Or do I have to add something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147341/426227) solves the issue for me:

```
webView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
```

If anyone has a clue, please comment.